# Titanium.Platform.id DEPRECATED in 1.8.0

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

What to use instead of Titanium.Platform.id in 1.8.0 ?

Thanks...

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Platform.createUUID-method.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As  Muhammad Zeeshan has suggested, I solved it by :-

```
var deviceID = Ti.Platform.createUUID ; OR Titanium.Platform.createUUID
alert(deviceID);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's new Titanium.App.installId property comes with SDK 2.0.1.